# How to group data in laravel and format it to this?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 $collection = collect(
[
  ["md_id" => 1, "hs_id" => 1234],
  ["md_id" => 2, "hs_id" => 5432],
  ["md_id" => 3, "hs_id" => 1234],
]
);
```

Hi, I want to group this collection into group, but not grouped by keys.

This is what I need in my response, group with a new property:

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "hs_id": 1234,
      "type" : "pt,
      "group_data": [
        {"md_id" : 1},
        {"md_id" : 3},
      ]
    },
    {
      "hs_id": 5432,
      "type" : "kl,
      "group_data": [
        {"md_id" : 2},
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
$data = $mds->groupBy("hs_id");
return response()->json(compact("data"));
```

and the response is a group of data by keys(hs_id).

Comment: Where is `type` coming from? Also, why is `md_id`3 in the first group?

Comment: @Rwd my bad, fixed it. I tried to make it short. the type is a new property I want to add, after grouping it by hs_id. this is the part where i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
$collection = collect([
    ["md_id" => 1, "hs_id" => 1234],
    ["md_id" => 2, "hs_id" => 5432],
    ["md_id" => 3, "hs_id" => 1234],
]);

$data = $collection
    ->groupBy('hs_id')
    ->map(fn ($items, $hsId) => [
        'hs_id'      => $hsId,
        'group_data' => $items->map(fn ($item) => Arr::only($item, 'md_id'))->toArray(),
    ])
    ->values();

return compact('data');
```

You'll need to add `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;` to the file as well.